# check shuffled words in string to avoid duplicate entry

Tags: python

I wanted to create a pipeline before saving data into database to avoid duplicate entries

for example

```
 1. 364 Lane Debs
 2. 364 Debs Lane
 3. 365 Lane Debs
 4. 364 debs lane
```

Now the  entry 1,2,4 are same with shuffled words and where 3 has different number so it indicate different address.

Kindly suggest me approach

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not a very scalable and optimized approach for this problem. Instead you can use `frozenset` version of splitted words as the keys of a dictionary in order to save lines regardless of the order of their words and use `str.lower()` to ignore the case-sensitivity. Also in order to keep track if the actual lines you can preserver the indices.

```
In [1]: s = """ 1. 364 Lane Debs
   ...:  2. 364 Debs Lane
   ...:  3. 365 Lane Debs
   ...:  4. 364 debs lane"""

In [8]: lines = s.splitlines()    
In [9]: {frozenset(line.lower().split()[1:]):ind for ind, line in enumerate(lines)}

Out[7]: {frozenset({'364', 'debs', 'lane'}): 3,
         frozenset({'365', 'debs', 'lane'}): 2}
```

Or, instead of the indices you could save the lines:

```
In [10]: {frozenset(line.lower().split()[1:]):line for ind, line in enumerate(lines)}
Out[10]: 
{frozenset({'364', 'debs', 'lane'}): ' 4. 364 debs lane',
 frozenset({'365', 'debs', 'lane'}): ' 3. 365 Lane Debs'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [
    {'address': 364, 'words': 'Lane Debs'},
    {'address': 364, 'words': 'Debs Lane'},
    {'address': 365, 'words': 'Lane Debs'},
    {'address': 364, 'words': 'debs lane'},
]

unique = {
    (d['address'], tuple(sorted(d['words'].casefold().split()))): d
    for d in data
}.values()
```

This produces (on my machine):

```
[{'address': 365, 'words': 'Lane Debs'},
 {'address': 364, 'words': 'debs lane'}]
```

Your next problem is deciding which of duplicate entries is the 'right' one.